# Session variable not working [PHP & MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a table (`news`) with different column names. With my code, a new row with these can be added to the database with a text post, which is then echoed in my website.

However, just recently, it stopped working and I noticed that every column name would get updated normally except the one which defines what user has made said post (`idUSERS`). It has just stopped working recently, and the website outputs no error when I run the code. I use `$_SESSION["idUSERS"]` to get the current logged in user's ID

```
<?php

session_start();

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "intranet";

    // Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: Please try again later" . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

//$fecha = date("d-m-y");
$fecha = $_POST['news_date'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, description, date ,tipo, idUSERS)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['txtTitle']."', '".$_POST['txtNews']."', '".$fecha."', '".$_POST['cboTipo']."', '".$_SESSION["idUSERS"]."')";


    $result =  $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();

header("Location: DelkoINT_home.php");


?>
```

Database ref. image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4y94.png

```
<?php

session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "intranet";

// Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

$sql = "Select * from login_info where loginUsername ='".$_POST['username']."' and loginPassword ='".$_POST['password']."'";

$result =  $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result ->num_rows >0) {
            $row= $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION["idLOGIN"]= $row["idLOGIN"];
            $_SESSION["idUSERS"]= $row["idUSERS"];
            $_SESSION["admin"]= $row["user_type"];
            $_SESSION["surname"]= $row["userSurname"];
            header("Location: intranet/DelkoINT_home.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "<font color='red'>The username or password is incorrect!</font><br/ > 
            <a href = 'Delko_login.php'>Click here to go back</font></a>";
        }


    $conn->close(); 

?>
```

Session data `var_dump` on the MySQL writing page:

```
array(4) { 
         ["idLOGIN"]=> string(1) "2" 
         ["idUSERS"]=> NULL 
         ["admin"]=> string(1) "1" 
         ["surname"]=> NULL 
}
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Have you echoed out the query to verify that the query looks like it should, and that `$_SESSION["idUSERS"]` has the value you think it should?

Comment: I am aware of that, but this is a school project only.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a school project or not. You can ignore the security aspects and instead take advantage of not ever having to worry about quoting issues: no more making sure that the quotes are correct and that the data you're inputting doesn't have a quote that's throwing off the whole query.

Comment: @FrancoSoto the earlier you understand that security is important the better. Even though it is a school project you can still learn a lot - and actually school is the best place to learn to get in to the habit of doing things properly. Ignoring security concerns because it is a school project is not a smart idea.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_SESSION);` tell you, after the `session_start();` call?

Comment: Fair enough, I understand the importance of security, which is something I will have to self-teach and definitely implement in my next project, and if I have time I will do so in this one first.

Anyways, echoing the session returns an "Undefined index: idUSERS"

Comment: can you show where  session is saving `idUSERS` ?

Comment: First thing you do when debugging: Enable error-reporting! Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` directly after `<?php`, it might give you a clue.

Comment: I edited my post with the code which shows where the session is saving. Also, the error reporting didn't show me anything.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting within the `if ($result ->num_rows >0) {` block?

Comment: @FrancoSoto ok, so show us the code (*in your question*) where you set the value of `idUSERS`

Answer (score -1):

what i am able to interpret is that your have issue in the way you format your query request and assigning values to them. 
you should write sql statement in following way

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO booking ( EMAIL, PASENGER_NAME,  
     CONTACT_NUMBER, UNIT_NUM, STREET_NUM, STREET_NAME, SUBURB, 
     DESTINATION_SUBURB, PICK_DATE_TIME, BOOKING_DATE_TIME  ) 
             VALUES ( '{$_SESSION['EMAIL']}', '$Passenger_Name', 
            '$Phone', '$Unit_num', '$Street_num', '$Street_name', 
            '$Suburb', '$Dest_Suburb','$Pickup_Date_Time',
            '$current_time' )";
```

what I meant is that you write SQL statement without double quotes especially where you define session variable. instead write that like `{$_SESSION['EMAIL']}`.. Same for others if you are using it $_POST format then you can write it as `{$_POST['txtTitle']}`, `{$_POST['txtNews']}`, `{$_SESSION['idUSERS']}`. Also check that you define session variable on previous page such as  `$_SESSION['idUSERS']= $_POST['idusers']` and you are using letters in write format like lowercase and uppercase matters. Just do this and i am sure you will definately resolve your problem.

If you then also get a problem let me know then in that case i will tell you a trick which can help you finding the error point in your code.